# Calculating bi-Lipschitz constants

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that we have an $L$ bi-Lipschitz function $f:S\to U$, where $S$ is the square $S:=\{(x,y):|x|\leq 1,|y|\leq 1\}$ and $U$ is the upper hemisphere $U:=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1,z\geq 0\}$.

**Questions:**

(1) Is there a way to calculate the smallest bi-Lipschitz  constant  for which there exists such a function?

(2) More generally is there some condition (necessary and/or sufficient)  we should impose on a compact surface $U$ so that there is a bi-Lipschitz map form $S$ to $U$?

(3) Can we say anything about the smallest bi-Lipschitz constant in this case assuming that we know the geometry of the surface?

Any references about where to learn more on bi-Lipschitz maps between metric spaces are welcome.

Comment: What is your motivation for calculating the smallest bi-Lipschitz constant explicitly? I ask because in most mathematical discussions I've seen where the bi-Lipschitz concept is applied, knowing one explicit bi-Lipschitz constant is usually just fine; knowing the smallest one usually doesn't come up.

Comment: @Lee Mosher The map $f$ I described in my question is used in the construction of Zorich maps which are higher dimensional analogues of the exponential map in the complex plane. So you are right just knowing that such a map exists is fine. However I was wondering whether or not there is a lower bound to that constant. Also the question on the more general setting seems interesting to me and something like that might have been studied before and is maybe standard.